# Show Lex response in Sumerian 3D HTML

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, amazon-sumerian

I have a Amazon Sumerian Chat Bot connected to Amazon's Lex.

Currently, the chatbot responds back to the user in voice only.

How do I connect Lex to a 3D HTML entity in Sumerian to display the Lex response?

Comment: one this about HTML3D is that it will not work as expected in VR mode. If you are using it as a webVR, then it's fine. But for VR it may not render properly.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this tutorial, it will explain you how to do it : 
https://docs.sumerian.amazonaws.com/tutorials/create/beginner/lex-html/

As you can see in the tutorial, you can fetch the lex response via a custom script by invoking the following :

> ctx.entity.getData('lexResponse')